# What option specified the location of the generated RPM?

Tags: linux, centos, rpm, rpmbuild

I have noticed that, when building rpm files, that most end up in `/usr/src/redhat/RPMS/i386` (building 32bit).  Some though, incl one we roll in-house, writes the rpm files to `./i386`.... so the file winds up in `/usr/src/redhat/i386`.  I have compared the standard spec file (it's openssl that's giving me the trouble) to ours and I cannot see what could be causing the problem.

Unmolested tarball copied to `/usr/src/redhat/SOURCES`.

Building with `cd /usr/src/redhat; rpmbuild -bb ./SPECS/openssl.spec`

Here's my spec file (stripped of the boring build and install-related bits):

```
%define debug_package %{nil}
%define libmaj 1
%define libmin 0
%define librel 1
%define librev l
Release: 1

Summary: Secure Sockets Layer and cryptography libraries and tools
Name: openssl
Version: %{libmaj}.%{libmin}.%{librel}%{librev}
License: Freely distributable
Group: System Environment/Libraries
Source: %{name}-%{version}.tar.gz
URL: http://www.openssl.org/
Packager: Damien Miller <djm@mindrot.org>
BuildRoot: /var/tmp/%{name}-%{version}-root
AutoReqProv: yes
Provides: libcrypto.so.6 libssl.so.6

%description
blah blah

%prep

%setup

%build

./Configure --prefix=/usr threads shared linux-elf
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd` make depend
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd` make

%install
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT
...    

%clean
rm -rf $RPM_BUILD_ROOT

%files 
%defattr(-, root, root)
...

%pre

%post
/sbin/ldconfig

%postun
/sbin/ldconfig
```

And the [stock spec file can be found here](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/openssl.spec).

Answer (score 1):

There's a RPM variable you can define `_topdir` to move the default output folder of the `BUILD`, `RPMS`, `SOURCES`, `SPECS` and `SRPMS` folders.

There are two ways to define this:

1. Create `.rpmmacros` in the your folder and add `%_topdir /path`
2. When you call `rpmbuild` add `--define`:

   - `rpmbuild --define "_topdir /path" -bb $specfile`

Comment: Thanks jas, but that doesn't address the question, which is, what is the difference between the two spec files that would cause one to go to the RPMS/i386 folder and the other not.